# Difference between E[X] of a binary variable and the E[X] when X ~ B(n, p)?

Tags: statistics

I read E[X]=0*P(X=0)+1*P(X=1)=P(X=1) is the expected value of a binary random variable.  But also that E[X]=np when talking about X~B(n, p).

Why is it that they do not compute the same thing if both are talking about a binary variable? Or what am I missing out?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first one is a Bernoulli variable, the second is Binomial; Bin(1,p) is the same as Ber(p).

Comment: $B(n,p)$ is the notation for the binomial distribution.

Comment: "if both are talking about a binary variable" No. The binomial is not "binary" (except if n=1) since it can take n+1 values.

Comment: @Did Could you explain that alittle bit more please? From what I understood, in a binomial distribution, each Xi could take the value of either 1 or 0 therefore it would be a binary case but I see is not the case

Comment: You are confusing binomial distributions with their representations as the distributions of sums of independent Bernoulli random variables.